# Как передать список в запрос к fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, fastapi

Как передать массив в функцию? Строку разобрался как передавать, а массив не получается

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.post('/api/test/')
def get_test(queries: list):
    return queries
```

Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в логах

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55807 - "POST /api/test/ HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55807 - "POST /api/test HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: Используйте post хэндлер (вместо get) и передавайте список как json в теле POST запроса.

Comment: А если в `get` запросе? То надо через `/api/test/{queries}`?

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Если вам нужно передавать что-то более сложное, чем просто строки или числа, используйте post (или put) запросы.

Comment: @insolor хорошо, спасибо, а как это в коде должно выглядеть?

Comment: Просто меняете `@app.get('/api/test/')` на `@app.post('/api/test/')`. С клиента отправляете список в виде json в body запроса.

Comment: @insolor посмотрите вопрос, обновил

Comment: Не нужно queries, просто передаете список: `["test"]`

Comment: @insolor тоже самое получается

Comment: Не может то же самое получиться. Вот все работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZGaM.png

Comment: Да вроде и через `get` уже можно, вот примеры: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я ошибся, нужно было доки смотреть. Но конечно передача параметров через `.../api/test/?queries=1&queries=2` выглядит как изврат.

Comment: @insolor Если с одинаковым названием параметра, то да, фигня какая-то. Ну, я не вникал в детали )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через запрос GET (по мотивам примера из документации [Query parameter list / multiple values](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values)):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
app = FastAPI()
@app.get('/api/test/')
def get_test(queries: list = Query()):
    return queries
```

Запрос:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/test/?queries=1&queries=2&queries=3"
```

Ответ:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

---

На мой взгляд, для передачи на сервер чего-то более сложного чем одиночные строки или числа (в принципе, когда семантически (по смыслу) нам нужно что-то передать, а не получить (***get***)) лучше использовать POST или PUT запросы, тогда и данные можно будет передать в теле запроса в виде JSON.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.post('/api/test/')
def get_test(queries: list):
    return queries
```

Запрос:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/test/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[1,2,3]"
```

Ответ:

```
[1,2,3]
```